# How to set Text button

Tags: android, adapter

i have a custom_layout_dish

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:weightSum="10">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_Dish"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="6"
            android:src="@drawable/dau_phu_luot_van"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="3.5"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_NameDish"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Pepsi"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_Price"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="30.000"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_Order"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_add"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

and activity_orderfood

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_Cart"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Xem Hóa Đơn" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv_dish"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/btn_Cart"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
```

So, how to setText btn_Cart (activity) when I click btn_Order (custom_layout)
In OrderFoodActivity I create

```
public void ShowQuantityOrder(int quantity){
    btnCart.setText("Xem Giỏ Hàng " + quantity);
}
```

and

```
holder.btnOrder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int tongsoluong = chiTietGoiMonDAO.getTongSoLuong(magoimon);
                OrderFood orderFoodActivity = new OrderFoodActivity ();
                orderFoodActivity .ShowQuantityOrder(tongsoluong);
            }
        });
```

but It's not working pls help me I want when click btn_Order change text btn_Cart like "Xem Giỏ Hàng " + quantity, please help me. I using adapter

Comment: Where are you initializing the btnCart object?

Comment: Never create Activity by `new OrderFoodActivity()`, because activity have lifecycle.
Use `startActivity` instead

Comment: @GHH , I think he did that just to call the method with a object but yeah, it was just unnecessary in this case. He should be able to directly call **ShowQuantityOrder()**.

Comment: @SujalKumar btnCart in OrderFoodActivity and btnOrder in Adapter

Comment: Can you paste the whole code of Adapter and your activity? Something is confusing me.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1s-Z3vI9f5g0GPgB8_BVZh6L75Wv9CMWw/view?usp=sharing
you can get my source code here, and you can contact me in fb is: https://facebook.com/odaychicocainickclone/ or instagram: hanjos0609